# visual c# 2010 communicating between two projects

Tags: c#, winforms, variables, kinect, projects

I am trying to create a windows form project, and use speech recognition for the Kinect with the Kinect to Windows SDK. I have

- the form application project (p1) and
- the Kinect speech project (p2) which is a command prompt.

I made it a command prompt because it was the easiest way to do things. Anyway, I have read and found two things about this.

1)I found out how to run two projects at the same time in the same solution.

2) I also found out how to add references to get classes from each project to the other.

So, how would I get variables from each project? Just by using project references, or something? P2 can recognize speech and save it to variables, if that counts for anything.

Comment: do you want to use shared variables between both projects?

Comment: @sleiman Yes, I do want to share variables, so I can get info from one project to the other.

Comment: If you want to create single instance of object shared between two projects use Singleton pattern, but you should be aware of its pros and cons, Read it [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228164/on-design-patterns-when-to-use-the-singleton) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604844/pros-and-cons-of-using-singleton-pattern-in-dal)

Comment: Are you using two projects in the same solution? or two different solutions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I made it a command prompt because it was the easiest way to do things.

That sounds like the problem. It sounds like really you should be looking at making your Kinect project a class library. Then you can just call into that class library from the Windows Forms application.

If you want a "test bed" console app, you can always write one which also references the [class library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3707x96z.aspx).

Note that generally you shouldn't be sharing *variables* between projects - they're implementation details in most well-encapsulated systems - but you would create types which expose properties, appropriate methods etc.

Comment: I never thought of trying a class library. Ill give it a go. I tried (and miserably failed) to put my Kinect methods into a class and executing a command, but then I realized that the console has a loop, where the class doesn't. I just want to find the easiest way.

Comment: @cakeisajoke: You would quite possibly want to put that looping within the class library, running it from a separate thread. It's hard to know without seeing the code though.

Comment: Oh no! Jon skeet is starting Kinect?!?!?!? I will gain no furthur rep from this point on :(. +1 as this is what I did do for speech and another project combined

Comment: @OutlawLemur: I know absolutely nothing about the Kinect. It just seemed an obvious answer to give :)

Comment: @JonSkeet Oh that's a relieve ;). It is an interesting field though

Answer (score 2):

Here's a couple of options if I'm understanding you right:

1. Add those variables to your classes as properties then

   `using Solution.MyNamespace;`
   in the class that uses the other project
2. If you have variables that need to be independent, consider adding a class library project called Abstract or something that both projects reference

I hope this might help,
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to use named pipes for interprocess communication.

MSDN has the references to use the name pipes API [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.pipes.namedpipeclientstream.aspx).

Named pipes are part of the .NET framework and are a reliable method for communication without having to worry about access permissions on files.

To go down the static variable path, you would need to run a single process and turn one project into a dll and load the Program Main manually.

Of course you dont even need to use static variables but use synchronisation on reference variables passed in at load time. I would probably go this method if you didnt need to run two separate processes.

Just depends on what your goal is for having the projects separate processes.

Answer (score 0):

Like @JonSkeet said, create a class library, then you can save the information like this:

```
    public class SpeechRecognizer
    {
        public List<string> SpeechRecognized = new List<string>
        {

        };

        public void SaveRecognizedSpeech(string foundSpeech)
        {
            SpeechRecognized.Add(foundSpeech);
        }
    }
```

In code:

```
        SpeechRecognizer sr = new SpeechRecognizer();
        sr.SaveRecognizedSpeech("blah blah");
        sr.SaveRecognizedSpeech("BLAH BLAH");
        Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", sr.SpeechRecognized[0], sr.SpeechRecognized[1]);
        Console.Read();
```

Oh and to make your whole program know variables(I hope these are both in the same solution!) make them `public`. Hope this helps!